# C preprocessor macro that expands "hello world" to HelloWorld

Tags: objective-c, c

Is it possible to write a C preprocessor macro that would expand `macroName("hello world")` to `HelloWorld`?

I'd like to use it for my tests in Objective-C so that instead of:

```
- (void)testBreathingFrequenciesEuqalWhenIdentical { ... }
```

I could write:

```
- (void)testThat("breathing frequencies equal when identical") { ... }
```

Comment: As an experienced C programmer I find the first form more readable and less error prone than the second.

Comment: Quite weird, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: It certainly possible to do what you want using string operation and reflection but not using macros only? Also, really weird thing to do.

Comment: At best you could write a `testThat` macro that would compare the string to a fixed set of possibilities and select a method to call.  But the test would be at run time, and a slight variation in spacing, spelling, etc, would lead to an error that the compiler would not see but would occur at runtime.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I didn't ask whether is't "weird" or not. The question is whether it's possible to achieve the task using C preprocessor or not.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks for the input. I like the second one better, especially when it get longer than that.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic: to answer your question: I'd say "no". AFAIK there is now way to process the parameters and transform them (in your case removing spaces and transforming 1st letters of the words to upper case) with the C preprocessor. But I'm still curious why you would need that.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic: if you make a typo in the parameter, the program would compile fine but the problem(s) would arise at runtime. How would you handle this ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for the input. As for why I need it: I use `XCTest` for tests. However, ever since I tried _Kiwi_, _Cedar_ and others, I miss the ability to name my tests with spaces. That's it basically.

Answer (score 1):

No, once a string literal, always a string literal

Answer (score 0):

No, C preprocessor have no capabilities to convert strings to tokens. Also it does not have capabilites to change case.

**Most used way is do opposite task**: convert token to string. Following macros suitable for this:

```
#define XSTR(a) #a
#define STR(a) XSTR(a)
#define XCAT(a,b) a##b
#define CAT(a,b) XCAT(a,b)
```

`STR(a)` is converting token to string, so `STR(abc)` will give `"abc"`. `CAT(a,b)` concatenates tow tokens to a new token, so `CAT(foo,bar)` will give `foobar`. (XCAT and XSTR do the same except they do not expand arguments)

So you may write something macro like `testThatV(Breating,Frequencies,Equal,When,Identical)`, which could convert its arguments to token and string. Anyway, you will need set of macros like `testThatI(a)`, `testThatII(a,b)`, `testThatIII(a,b,c)` etc. because standard preprocessor cannot deal with variable number of arguments.

Comment: Why would he want to stringize anything? He wants the opposite.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, I understand. I highlighted why I wrote this.